# All tabs/windows in MOST apps are scrolling to the bottom or right

Tags: shortcut-keys, mouse, google-chrome, libreoffice, dock

Can someone please tell me why most of all my apps automatically scrolling to the right or bottom so I can only view the last page or window or tab. I've changed my mouse and keyboard (wired). For example, if I open "Show applications" in the dock, and put the mouse over the screen to select anything on the first page, the view automatically changes so I can only see the apps on the second page.
Likewise, Chrome only lets me select the right-most tab. If I want to view an earlier tab to the left, it automatically quickly goes back to the right-most tab. The only way to see and stay on tabs to the left, is to move them so that they are the right-most tab.
And apparently this is selective, it happens in chrome, the show applications, calibre, libre calc; but in libre writer I can stay on page 1 of my doc, but if I press the ctrl (with the intention of then hitting ctrl+s to save the document, libre thinks I hitting ctrl and scrolling to make the doc smaller, and smaller, and smaller.
How can I fix this? I've been running 22.04 for a long time, but this started happening only a few days ago, and I did not (intentionally) download anything new. Please keep in mind I'm a total amateur, and have only used the terminal successfully a few times.
I apologize for the length of this post.

Comment: That's probably a good thing.

Comment: Update: Reinstalled the system, no joy. Using Firefox, I can go to tabs on the left, but if I go to google maps it quickly zooms all the way in (+). Anyone else? Please? Thanks.